# In Mount Weather, why is radiation from nuclear fallout not present in water etc?

Tags: the-100

Wouldn't the nuclear war have caused radiation throughout the food and water supply? Living underground hardly helps. It's not like solar radiation is the problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: The radiation in The 100 is strange, to say the least: doesn't affect the Sky People and the tribes at all, but some animals are affected and it more or less melts down the inhabitants of Mount Weather as soon as they get a whiff of it. That's not how radiation works in real life.

Comment: @Sava Yeah, I actually enjoy The 100 a fair bit, but I tend to always say, "The 100 is a great show... you have to ignore everything you know about radiation and how it works, but if you can do that, it's remarkably good sci-fi."

Comment: @starpilotsix that also applies to physics, chemistry, health, space exploration, cryogenetics, weaponry, wood environments, radio transmission and programming, but oh yeah that's a good popcorn show.

Comment: @Sava The tribes were hand-waved as having evolved to tolerate the radiation. Some of the desert people appear to still be evolving to that. The sky people were commented on in season 2 as being genetically engineered to withstand space radiation (although that struck me as a DeM added in--to explain a bump in the storyline.) So there are lots of hand wavy explanations for why things are the way they are, but it looks like the writers think radiation is only in the air. It would start there, and then work into the entire ecosystem.

Comment: @DPT true, but Mount Weather does not interact with "the ecosystem", it's supposed to be an ecosystem of its own (in the show, I mean), as pointed out by the fact that they produce their own goods. I updated my answer with the relevant quotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Mount Weather is self-sufficient.

The radiation in food and water would only be an issue if the Mountain Men were gathering it from the outside, but that is not the case. Mount Weather is completely sealed from the outside, radiation can't possibly enter it (until *someone* pulls the right lever, of course).

#### In-universe

In "The 48", first episode of the second season, Dante gives Clarke a quick tour of Mount Weather. When they enter one of the rooms, he mentions an under ground reservoir as well as a hydrophonic farm producing their food. We've seen such things in the show (hydrofarm in season 5, the ones on the Ark...).

> Sorry about the noise. Hydroelectric power from Philpott Dam. Fresh water from our own underground reservoir. Fresh food from our hydroponic farm.

Here's the map Clarke uses later in the same episode. If [this larger image](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/thehundred/images/7/74/Tumblr_inline_ndvf7womCQ1sgaq1v.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20141118233954) is of value, there are several other equipments as well as the area labelled as "Agriculture" (or Horticulture on the larger one). Among those is a life support (402), which likely operates the rest of the rooms. Mount Weather being connected to a nearby lake, it's not a stretch to imagine that this water may be filtered somehow, to refill the aforementioned reservoir.

[image: Mount Weather map]

Granted, the show's science is quite handwave-prone when it comes to radiation, but since all season 2 revolves around the fuss it would be if even a little radiation came into the bunker, it's implied Mount Weather was completely shut off from it.

#### Out-of-universe

[Mount Weather Emergency Operations Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Weather_Emergency_Operations_Center) is an actual facility located in Virginia, built in the 60s in case of a nuclear war. Unfortunately, the United States government is not big on giving tours of top-secret facilities, but in 2001, *Time* published [quite a detailed article](http://content.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,156041,00.html) on the building.

It basically reads "yup, totally autonomous" for 20+ paragraphs (and a couple "vulnerability issues" ones at the end), but here are the relevant ones on the matter of food and water:

> Mount Weather is a virtually self-contained facility. Aboveground, scattered across manicured lawns, are about a dozen buildings bristling with antennas and microwave relay systems. **An on-site sewage- treatment plant, with a 90,000-gal.-a-day capacity, and two tanks holding 250,000 gal. of water could last some 200 people more than a month; underground ponds hold additional water supplies.** Not far from the installation's entry gate are a control tower and a helicopter landing pad. The mountain's real secrets are not visible at ground level.

...

> **Several underground ponds were carved from solid rock -- some of them, according to Fowler's estimates, were 10 ft. deep and 200 ft. across. One was to be a reservoir for drinking water;** others were used to cool the air pumped through the complex's massive mainframe computers to prevent them from overheating. Side tunnels were dug, and more than 20 cavernous offices were put in, some shored up with concrete. To withstand the severe exterior shock of a nuclear blast, the roof areas of the tunnels and rooms were reinforced with 21,000 iron bolts sunk 8 to 10 ft. into the rock, according to records at the National Archives.

...

> Fowler and other current and former Mount Weather employees describe an eerie complex that could be turned into the U.S.'s underground capital in an instant. Standby sleeping quarters were set up to accommodate hundreds of government officials. Because the country's Emergency Broadcast System could be obliterated in a nuclear strike, a radio-and-television studio was included so that the President or other key officials could address the nation, providing people with emergency instructions and telling them that at least some units of government were intact and carrying on. Diesel engines were installed to generate electricity in an underground utility plant called the power chamber. **Refrigerators were brought in for food storage. A cafeteria became part of the complex, as well as a hospital.**

If we tie those together, one can imagine that when the Mountain Men first entered Mount Weather, they relied on storaged food, then moved on to proceed their own.